# How to get sorted paged map by couple conditions using java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have some model object `Account` with list of fields, in simple case with two fields `String name` and `double margin`

And I need to get exact page of this accounts which is over some margin limit, sorted by margin & name. Each record should have margin as key, and Account as value.

I made this minimal example of code, but seems like sorting doesn't works well for me. So I wrap it in TreeMap, but it will cost extra memory and I hate it.
Probably should be wait to fix this inside of streams and add losted sort by name in case of equals margin

```
@Data
class Account {
    private final String name;
    private final double margin;

    private final static double MARGIN_LIMIT = 100;
    private final static int PAGE_SIZE = 3;

    private static Set<Account> accounts = new HashSet<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        accounts.add(new Account("user1", 200));
        accounts.add(new Account("user2", 100));
        accounts.add(new Account("user3", 150));
        accounts.add(new Account("user4", 175));
        accounts.add(new Account("user5", 75));
        accounts.add(new Account("user6", 110));

        Map<Double,Account> val = new TreeMap<Double,Account>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
        val.putAll(getClientsForClosing(2));
        System.out.println(val);
    }

    private static Map<Double, Account> getClientsForClosing(int page) {
        return accounts.stream()
                .filter(account -> account.getMargin() >= MARGIN_LIMIT)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Account::getMargin).reversed())
                .skip(PAGE_SIZE * (page - 1))
                .limit(PAGE_SIZE)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Account::getMargin, o -> o));
    }
}
```

Comment: *but seems like sorting doesn't works well for me* - exactly how?

Comment: after collect() I lost any sorting because toMap return HashMap

Comment: you have two choices - collect to a `LinkedHashMap` or use a `TreeMap` instead without `sorted`

Comment: LinkedHashMap looks much nicer then wrapping to TreeMap, thanks!

Comment: `wrapping` to `TreeMap`? `...collect(.. ... () -> new TreeMap(YourComparator))`

Comment: you also assume that `margin` is unique, in case it is not - this will fail, may be a `Map<Double, List<Account>>` instead?

Comment: I meant my example above. Your example is looks as good as answer below.

Comment: yep, you're right, I will think about a list of accounts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question and solution somehow are contradictory, on one hand you show code that sorts your entries by `margin` - which is a `double`; in this case there is a simpler way:

```
accounts.stream()
        .filter(account -> account.getMargin() >= MARGIN_LIMIT)
        .skip(PAGE_SIZE * (page - 1))
        .limit(PAGE_SIZE)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
               Account::getMargin,
               () -> new TreeMap<Double, List<Account>>(Comparator.reverseOrder()),
               Collectors.toList()));
```

If you want to sort *by both* `margin` and `name` and still keep the definition as `Map<Double, List<Account>>`, you will have to stick with a `LinkedHashMap`:

```
accounts.stream()
        .filter(account -> account.getMargin() >= MARGIN_LIMIT)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Account::getMargin)
                          .reversed()
                          .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Account::getName)))
        .skip(PAGE_SIZE * (page - 1))
        .limit(PAGE_SIZE)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
              Account::getMargin,
              x -> {
                 List<Account> list = new ArrayList<>();
                 list.add(x);
                 return list;
              },
              (left, right) -> {
                  left.addAll(right);
                  return left;
              },
              LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: Sorting by both margin and name will be better. Second is nice solution.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like that fix exactly what you are looking for

```
private static Map<Double, Account> getClientsForClosing(int page) {
    return accounts.stream()
            .filter(account -> account.getMargin() >= MARGIN_LIMIT)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Account::getMargin)
                    .reversed().thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Account::getName)))
            .skip(PAGE_SIZE * (page - 1))
            .limit(PAGE_SIZE)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Account::getMargin, o -> o,
                    (oldVal, newVal) -> oldVal, LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

Comment: pretty nice answer for a first timer! one plus. I am not sure about the merge though, you are simply *dumping* an `Account` in case there is a clash, might not be what the OP wants

Comment: looks good but skipping accounts with same margin could become horrible bug at production. As @Eugene say at comments will be better to rewrite this code to get Map<Double, List<Account>> as result

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are correct, however I think `TreeSet` (instead of `TreeMap`) could be of great help to you:

```
TreeSet<Account> accounts = new TreeSet<>(
    Comparator.comparingDouble(Account::getMargin).reversed()
        .thenComparing(Account::getName));

// Then add all the accounts

Map<Double, List<Account>> result = accounts
    .headSet(new Account("zzzz", MARGIN_LIMIT)) // zzzz is the greatest string 
    .stream()                                   // I could think of at this time
    .skip(PAGE_SIZE * (page - 1))               // (it's quite late here)
    .limit(PAGE_SIZE)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Account::getMargin));
```

This solution uses the [`TreeSet.headSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#headSet-E-boolean-) method, which fits like a glove for what you are trying to do. Then, we turn to stream to skip and limit elements and finally collect to the desired data structure.